# Hibernate EntityManager merge() does not update modified value when null (false)

Tags: hibernate, merge, persistence, entitymanager

I have a detached entity with a boolean value. If the value in my database is currently 0 (false) and my detached entity is set to true when I call a merge() it behaves as I expect and updates the value in the database to true. However, if the value in the detached entity is set to false and the database is currently 1 (true) the value in the database will not be updated. It seems I have no way to set it back to false.

*Additional information:*

I also have a varchar field which behaves similarly. If the detached entity field is not null the field will be updated. Yet, if it is null I have no way to set the database varchar back to null (yes it is configured to be nullable and optional).

I have turned on org.hibernate.SQL debugging and I have traced this issue to the actual SQL update call. For whatever reason when the detached entity boolean is false it will not be included in the update statement (regardless of the database state), same with the varchar field if it is null. What I find even more curious is that all other fields (the boolean and varchar are new) are always included in the update statement even if the current detached entity does not differ from the database. Which to my understanding is not how merge() is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

I did not actually solve this issue, but I have an ugly work around.

I created a new method in the DAO to verify the update:

```
public void verifyUpdate(MyEntity alreadyMergedEntity) {
    MyEntity shouldBeUpdatedButNot = getByName(alreadyMergedEntity.getName());

    if (shouldBeUpdatedButNot.getVarChar() != alreadyMergedEntity.getVarChar()) {
        shouldBeUpdatedButNot.setVarChar(alreadyMergedEntity.getVarChar());
    }
    if (shouldBeUpdatedButNot.isChecked() != alreadyMergedEntity.isChecked()) {
        shouldBeUpdatedButNot.setChecked(alreadyMergedEntity.isChecked());
    }
    em.flush();
}
```

If you have a better answer please update so I can remove this ugly mess :)

Comment: For what it is worth, I ended up modifying this to just update the values in shouldBeUpdatedButNot regardless of whether they were equal or not.